# Spring MVC cannot find JSPs when deployed into embedded Jetty 8 server

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to run embedded Jetty server and deploy Spring MVC application into it, but there is a problem of resources mapping - particulary I can't map spring mvc controller so that it can find my JSPs.

**Configuration:**

- jetty-8.1.8.v20121106
- Spring 3.2

**Jetty Server Configuration**:

```
    Server server = new Server();

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
   //WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setBaseResource(Resource.newClassPathResource("webapp"));
    context.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    context.setContextPath("/");

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webAppContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    webAppContext.register(WebFaceSpringConfiguration.class);
    webAppContext.setServletContext(context.getServletContext());
    webAppContext.setParent(applicationContext);

    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DispatcherServlet(webAppContext)), "/");

    server.setHandler(context);
    server.setConnectors(jettyConnectors);
```

Folder *webapp* is in classpath, but in such configuration I have an error *Problem accessing /WEB-INF/pages/main-page.jsp* (which is actually located under *webapp*). So controller method is invoked, but view cannot be resolved.

I tried to use *WebAppContext* and wildcard mapping for Spring Dispatcher Servlet (/*), but it did not help - controller mapping is ignored or JSP cannot be found.

Comment: Can you post your error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a viewresolver, normal way looks this in xml

```
 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/" p:suffix=".jsp"/>
```

Comment: actually I have one. And it looks active, since my controller method returns "main-page" view name, but error contains full path to jsp file.

Comment: @viator I am not familar with jetty... sorry can;t help anymore